# How to Set the Default Color in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this Javascript that changes the background color on click, but when the page loads the background color is already set. How do I fix this? I do not see how to hide the "active" class when the page loads only to reveal it when the button is clicked. Everything else in the code is working fine. I have been searching for the answer for a long time.

```js
var newItemCounter = 1;
var ourList = document.getElementById("our-list");
var ourButton = document.getElementById("our-button");
var ourHeadline = document.getElementById("our-headline");
var listItems = document.getElementById("our-list").getElementsByTagName("li");


ourList.addEventListener("click", activateItem);


function activateItem(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        ourHeadline.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
        for (i = 0; i < e.target.parentNode.children.length; i++) {
            e.target.parentNode.children[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
        e.target.classList.add("active");
    }
}

ourButton.addEventListener("click", createNewItem);


function createNewItem() {
    ourList.innerHTML += "<li>New item " + newItemCounter + "</li>";
    newItemCounter++;
}
```

```css
li {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.active {
    background-color: #FFFF02;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="our-headline">Click an item to replace this text.</h1>

<button id="our-button">Add New Item</button>

<ul id="our-list">
  <li class="active">First item</li> 
  <li class="active">Second item</li> 
  <li class="active">Third item</li> 
  <li class="active">Fourth item</li> 
  <li class="active">Fifth item</li> 
  <li class="active">Sixth item</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: well only add active when the `li` is clicked

Comment: All of your `li` have the class `.active` when the page loads. Just remove the classes from your html.

Comment: That worked Turnip. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `active` class from the default `li` items.

```js
var newItemCounter = 1;
var ourList = document.getElementById("our-list");
var ourButton = document.getElementById("our-button");
var ourHeadline = document.getElementById("our-headline");
var listItems = document.getElementById("our-list").getElementsByTagName("li");


ourList.addEventListener("click", activateItem);


function activateItem(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        ourHeadline.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
        for (i = 0; i < e.target.parentNode.children.length; i++) {
            e.target.parentNode.children[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
        e.target.classList.add("active");
    }
}

ourButton.addEventListener("click", createNewItem);


function createNewItem() {
    ourList.innerHTML += "<li>New item " + newItemCounter + "</li>";
    newItemCounter++;
}
```

```css
li {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.active {
    background-color: #FFFF02;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Javascript Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h1 id="our-headline">Click an item to replace this text.</h1>

  <button id="our-button">Add New Item</button>

  <ul id="our-list">
    <li>First item</li> 
    <li>Second item</li> 
    <li>Third item</li> 
    <li>Fourth item</li> 
    <li>Fifth item</li> 
    <li>Sixth item</li> 
  </ul>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice! It is working now. I see that the style is added later by the Javascript code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the class from the markup and let the Javascript handle adding the class.

```js
var newItemCounter = 1;
var ourList = document.getElementById("our-list");
var ourButton = document.getElementById("our-button");
var ourHeadline = document.getElementById("our-headline");
var listItems = document.getElementById("our-list").getElementsByTagName("li");


ourList.addEventListener("click", activateItem);


function activateItem(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        ourHeadline.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
        for (i = 0; i < e.target.parentNode.children.length; i++) {
            e.target.parentNode.children[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
        e.target.classList.add("active");
    }
}

ourButton.addEventListener("click", createNewItem);


function createNewItem() {
    ourList.innerHTML += "<li>New item " + newItemCounter + "</li>";
    newItemCounter++;
}
```

```css
li {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.active {
    background-color: #FFFF02;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Javascript Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h1 id="our-headline">Click an item to replace this text.</h1>

  <button id="our-button">Add New Item</button>

  <ul id="our-list">
    <li >First item</li> 
    <li >Second item</li> 
    <li >Third item</li> 
    <li >Fourth item</li> 
    <li >Fifth item</li> 
    <li >Sixth item</li> 
  </ul>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```